# Conventient way to store configuration and setup files for after reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows, reinstall, configure

So, my Windows 10 has been running slow and things that have been working previously is suddenly not working anymore.

I'm planning to do a full reinstall (wipe my entire disk), but I'm not looking forward to the usual 2-3 days of installing and configuring the different software I use (I'm a software developer, so there's quite many of them).

I want to keep some of my config files, for instance for VS Code, Windows Terminal, PowerShell etc., so I'm thinking of version controlling them or having them on my OneDrive. I'm also thinking of maybe generating a script installing applications for me - maybe just a Python script running chocolatey commands or something like that.

I'm sure a bunch of you has already done something like this before, and possibly in a better/easier way, but I wasn't able to find anything on this. Has anyone got any tips, links to git repos or blog posts that I can use for inspiration? How have you guys done things like this?

Comment: You need to find first what's the problem, just reinstalling might not fix it. The first suspect is the disk, so check its SMART data, run `chkdsk` and examine the Event Viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This was more of a general question for WHEN I actually reinstall. It's been a few years since the last time now, so I figured this is a good time to do a "full clean up" anyway.